# Is JavaMail attachment an instanceof InputStream?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to get a `java` program to automatically process `xml` content that is sent to the app as an attachment to an email.  I have been experimenting with different ways to query the components of an email message looking for `xml` files, and the only way that seems reliable is to poll the `bodypart`s.  **How can I best determine if a body part is an xml file, and then convert that xml file into an input stream automatically?**  I want to convert any `xml` attachment into an `inputstream` and then do further processing of the `inputstream`.

Here is what I imagine:

```
for(int y=1;y<=msg_count;y++){
    Message msg = inbox.getMessage(y);
    if(msg.getContent() instanceof Multipart){
        Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
        for(int a=0;a<mp.getCount();a++){
            BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(a);
            if(bp.getFileName()!=null){
                if(bp.getFileName().endsWith(".xml")){
                    if(bp.getContent() instanceof com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream){
                        InputStream myis = (InputStream)bp.getContent();
                        Blob blob = null;
                        byte[] content = IOUtils.toByteArray(myis);
                        try {blob = new SerialBlob(content);} 
                        catch (SerialException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                        catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that eclipse warns of an impeding compilation error where the code above reference `com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream`, even though System.out.println(bp.getContent()) returns `com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream` for the xml attachment in the code above.

Comment: "eclipse does not like" is not a detailed description of your problem and is unlikely to attract help from others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking if it's an instance of `com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream`, and if it is, you're casting to `java.io.InputStream`. So, in fact, all you should test is if it's an instance of `java.io.InputStream`. That's what's needed for the cast to succeed.

Whether it's a `com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream` or not is not important, and is an implementation detail.

Comment: Your answer assumes that `com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream` can be reliably cast as `java.io.InputStream`.  It works in this case, but I am not sure how generalizable it is.

Comment: No. My answer assumes that if you're casting to InputStream, then you're the one making this assumption. And that if you want to test if something is a java.io.InputStream to be sure that the cast is safe, then what you should use is `instanceof java.io.InputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

When a class isn't defined in your context you could do a getClass().getName() and string compare with your expected result instead of an instanceof.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for adding useful perspective.  But this does not get me past the eclipse compilation error warning.  the getClass().getName() in this case just returned `com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream`, which apparently can be cast as `java.io.InputStream`.

Comment: I didn't know if the actual class was important to you or not. I've developed with strange apis where you get classes and you what to check if you actually got what you expected but you didn't have the class in your context.

Answer (score 0):

There's so many assumptions in your code that it's important to ask what it is you're really trying to do...

Lots of attachments of many different kinds can be in XML format, do you really want to process all of them?  Saying that something is "XML" is only slightly more helpful than saying that it's "ASCII".  What kind of XML data are you expecting and what do you want to do with it?

Attachments may or may not have names, and attachments that are in XML format may or may not have a filename that ends in ".xml".

Who is sending the messages that you're trying to process?  Are they being sent my another program you know about, that only sends XML files with a ".xml" filename?  Or are you trying to process any arbitrary message sent by any mail program in any mailbox with attachments of any kind?

Knowing what you're really trying to do will help us recommend the best solution.

Comment: The emails containing `xml` files are sent from other applications using known email addresses only.  All files will contain an xml extension.  The contents of the `xml` files will undergo subsequent downstream processing to address the concerns that you raise.  I am trying to keep each question focused so that we can retain the integrity of the stack overflow format.

Comment: Explaining more of the background and requirements will help keep the questions focused and avoid the need to ask these clarifying questions.

Comment: This question was answered by others before you replied.  Your submissions to this posting have all been questions, which belong in the comments below the original posting.  You have not provided an answer to this question, so you should not have clicked the button that posted your submissions as an answer.

Comment: I appreciate any intention you might have to help. But StackOverflow is for narrow answers to narrow questions. Responders post comments at the end of an OP. The exchange of comments results in an answer before the responder posts it as an answer. We then delete our comments and clean up our questions/answers as necessary after the exchange of comments has resulted in answers. Your approach is at odds with this standard practice. Here is a post that explains proper etiquette to use on this site:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269993/placeholder-answers-will-update-with-answer-soon